# How could I remove these jagged shadows?

Tags: lighting, shadows

I tried removing these jagged shadows with the Shadow Terminator Offset slider in Blender 2.90 but they don't go away even if I crank it at 1, plus I'm getting horrible dark shadows all over the place by increasing this slider that much.

I used an 8K displacement texture applied to a subdivided plane with a Displace modifier. I then added a Subdivision Surface modifier with 5 levels of subdivision, totaling a whopping 10.5M vertices. I also tried Adaptive Subdivision but it didn't work as I left my PC rendering for 2 hours and it was still calculating...

How could I fix this issue?

[image]

Shadow Terminator @ 1.00

[image]

Full render

[image]

Comment: Given the images you’ve shown, it isn’t obvious to me that the issue isn’t simply caused by genuinely jagged geometry. Could you provide more details about the structure of your mesh, and possibly upload your .blend file?

Comment: Hey, so I'm using an 8K displacement texture applied to a subdivided plane with a Displace modifier. I then added a Subdivision Surface modifier with 5 levels of subdivision, totaling 10.5M vertices. I also tried Adaptive Subdivision but it didn't work as I left my PC rendering for 2 hours and it was still calculating...

Comment: It’s really difficult to tell from the information in your question whether what you’re seeing is really a shading artifact or just jagged geometry. It would be helpful to show screenshots of the relevant area of the mesh, and again, possibly to [upload your .blend file](https://pasteall.org/blend/).